# Upload image path-name is "System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper"

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

"ilan" is a table in my database, ilan has a column named "kapak_foto".

Here is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult ilanver(ilan ilan,HttpPostedFileBase kapak_foto)
        {

                if (kapak_foto != null)
                { 
                string kapakname = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(kapak_foto.FileName)
             + "-" + Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(kapak_foto.FileName);

                Image orjres = Image.FromStream(kapak_foto.InputStream);

                orjres.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/pics" + kapakname));

                ilan dbres = new ilan();
                dbres.kapak_foto = "/Content/images/pics" + kapakname;

                }
```

**The html part:**

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("ilanver", "ilanver", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data" }))

{   <input type="file" name="kapak_foto"/>}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I can not save the image path correctly, Upload image path-name reads “System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper”

Comment: Which variable in your code equals that? I can't see a variable called `path-name` in your example.

Comment: "dbres.kapak_foto = "/Content/images/pics" + kapakname;" should give me the path? I'm a newbie so if you have a solution i am eager to hear. I am trying to save the image in "/Content/images/pics + image name.

Comment: Try with this; orjres.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/pics/" + kapakname));

Comment: @serhat MERCAN just did it before you say, it saves the image correctly but i can't get the image path. I think there is something wrong about the last code line " dbres.kapak_foto = "/Content/images/pics/" + kapakname;"

Comment: dbres.kapak_foto = Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/pics/" + kapakname); if you want to use phisycal location. Otherwise, you want to use reference addres dbres.kapa_foto = "/content/images/pics/"+kapakname;

Comment: Still reads as “System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper”...

Comment: Which path is you want to get? The path of client location or the path of server side location?

Comment: I just want to get the photo path, like :"content/images/pics/picture5.jpg" then i will use it's url on another page. when i look at kapak_foto column in ilan table, it reads as “System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper”. There is not an url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly; the code is

```
orjres.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/pics/" + kapakname));
```

Second; if you will use the path of saved file, you must take the file location into antoher variable before to save;

```
var filePath = "/Content/images/pics/" + kapakname;
orjres.Save(Server.MapPath(filePath));

ilan dbres = new ilan();
dbres.kapak_foto = filePath;

// ... the other codes...

db.ilan.add(dbres); // if your databse name defined before as db!
db.SaveChanges();
```

If the filePath is correct for to save file, it can be usable for url.

Comment: Thank you ver much! I have just replaced the last code line with this one: var filepath = "/content/images/pics/" + kapakname;  ilan.kapak_foto = filepath;". It works lie charm...